# xCode Navigation Back Button not popping detailview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode6

Whenever I press on the 'go back' button on my final detail view, it wont go back to the table view.

I have a storyboard setup like this:

UITabViewController -> UINavigationController -> UITableView -> UINavigationController -> UIView (The detailview).

[image]

When I run my program I see the back button, but clicking it does nothing.

[image]

Here is the code for DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gobackBtn)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backbtn];

    [self configureView];
}

- (void)gobackBtn
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

As if `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` does nothing.

I'm out of ideas. Why does the backbutton not 'pop' the detailview?

Comment: You should not have the second `UINavigationController`

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Without the second navigation controller, i dont seem to have any navigation bar at all in the detail view: http://i.imgur.com/HskoyEk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your detail view controller is the root view controller of the navigation controller.  So 'popping' does nothing.  You need instead to dismiss the navigation controller.  Technically, you should use a delegate to tell your `TableViewController` to dismiss it, but I think

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

from within your `goBackButton` method of your detail view controller will do the trick.